# Which one is the same as find_(findTag, class_=findValue) of BeautifulSoup in webDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to use the same find method find(findClass, class_=findValue) of BeautifulSoup in Selenium, I searched but no what I need, can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just translate your BeautifulSoup code into CSS selector expression which is quite powerful, and then use [`find_elements_by_css()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)  :

```
# equivalent to : soup.find("div", class_="list-container")
driver.find_element_by_css("div.list-container")

# equivalent to : soup.find("div", class_="list-container").find_all("a")
driver.find_elements_by_css("div.list-container a")
```

Comment: link = soup.find("div", class_="list-container").find_all("a"), href = link.get("href"), above code is ok. but both of your answers got the same Exception....

Comment: As Alex pointed out, you need to learn the API of Selenium, read the documentation. In selenium you call `get_attribute("href")` on individual webelement to get the attribute value...

Comment: I got it by get_attribute. thanks for your advise. @har07

Comment: how can I convert this soup.find(findTag, id=findValue).find_all(linkTag) to driver.find_elements_by.....?

Comment: CSS selector expression for that would be : `findTag#findValue linkTag` or `findTag[id="findValue"] linkTag`. Learn more about [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
elements = []
classes = driver.find_elements_by_class(className)
for c in classes:
    l = c.find_elements_by_tag_name(tagName)
    if l:
        elements.extent(l)
```

is equlivent to

```
soup.findAll("div", { "class" : className})
```

Comment: Sorry, my original code is soup.find("div", class_="list-container").find_all("a"), so driver.find_elements_by_class("list-container") is OK?

Comment: @mikezang you will need to use a for loop to extract `a`.

Comment: The problem is I used that result to get("href"), but your code can't get, error is Exception: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get'...

Comment: @mikezang beautifulsoup and selenium web driver are different... you can't just "use" the methods from beautifulsoup in selenium... har07's solution should get you the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some tasks like click a button, use selenium API.

If you need to extract data from HTML code, you should use BeautiflSoup.

You can use selenium get the HTML code and then use BeautifulSoup to parse it:

```
html_source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
```

Comment: My question is how to avoid using BeautifulSoup...., My code is OK if use VeautifulSoup:)